Collection of not-numerical semi-group of $\mathbb{N}$
Let $k \in \mathbb{N^*}$ and $r$ a divisor of $k$.
Then :
$$M_{k,\ r}=\{k,\ k+r,\ k+2r,\ k+3r,\ \cdots\}$$
is a collection of proper semi-group of $\mathbb{N}$ for $+$ (classic addition), which are not numerical semi-group
Do you know another infinite collection(s) of such semi-group, provided by a not-inductive formula (as above for $M_{k,\ r}$) ?
Sincerely yours,

Yo are considering $\mathbb N$ as a magma under addition or multiplication?

Sorry, I forgot to say I deal with magmas under addition.

It seems what you're interested in are the Numerical semigroups. Is that so?

I looked at wiki and I don't think. Because $0$ is not in $M_{k,\ r}$ and $\mathbb{N} \setminus M_{k,\ r}$ is not finite. I just deal with a collection of fair sub-magmas of $\mathbb{N}$.

@Lirone If you pick any numerical semigroup and take any number among the first elements out, you still have a sub-semigroup of $\mathbb N$; it just is no longer called a numerical semigroup. So I think you can find all sub-magmas of $\mathbb N$ (which are necessarily semigroups) this way.

In the comment above, I mean take any number of the first consecutive members, of course.

@armsa I agree, adding $0$ to my magma or not is not important here. But it isn't still a semigroup because actually, sub-magmas are not necessarily semigroups. Look at my example in my question : $\mathbb{N} \setminus M_{n,\ r}$ is not finite. So I really deal with magmas not semigroups.

@Lirone No, every sub-magma of $\mathbb N$ is a sub-semigroup. This is just because the operation is still associative. What I meant in the first comments is that you can use Examples of numerical semigroups, such as those in the linked web page, and exclude elements at will, provided you still have a magma (obviously, it has to be infinite, but not necessarily co-finite).

It will always be a co-finite subset of $d\mathbb N$ for some $d.$

@amrsa I'm looking for semi-groups $S$ that are not numerical semi-group because I want $(\mathbb{N} \setminus S)$  to be infinite. As the collection ($M_{k,\ r}$) given first in my posted question.

@Lirone I think the last comment from Thomas Andrews gives you everything you need.

Answer :
Let $S$ a semi-group generated by two elements $k$ and $k'$.
Then, if $k'$ and $k$ are co-prime, $S$ is a numerical semi-group.
If not, $S$ is a co-infinite semi-group.
This condition can be generalized to any number of elements generating the semi-group.
Sincerely yours.
Based on this Theorem:
Let $S$ be the subsemi-group of $\mathbb{N}$ generated by $A$. Then, $S$ is a numerical semi-group if and only if $\gcd (A) = 1$. Moreover, every numerical semi-group arises in this way.
